# use android or PC as keyboard output for RPI3

Tags: linux, keyboard, android, input

I just installed raspbian lite on my pi3 and don't have a keyboard to set it up with, I need some way of sending keyboard output to the pi so that I can configure SSH, I have a PC running windows 10 and an android Marshmallow Phone, is this possible? ps. I don't want to mod any kernels. if there is an app available for free, I'll try that. thanks

Comment: *"keyboard output for RPI3"* -- Input/output is referenced in relation to the CPU (in this case your RPi) rather than a peripheral device.  So the keyboard would be an input to the RPi.

Comment: That's true, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/), found via googling:

> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named `ssh`, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card from another computer. When the Pi boots, it looks for the `ssh` file. If it is found, SSH is enabled and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not matter; it could contain text, or nothing at all.
>
> If you have loaded Raspbian onto a blank SD card, you will have two partitions. The first one, which is the smaller one, is the boot partition. Place the file into this one.